# Running code between task creation and await with asyncio

Tags: python, python-asyncio

Using `asyncio` is it possible to create a task, then continue with the "main" code execution and await for the task results later on?

Consider the following code

```
from functools import reduce
import asyncio

async def a_task():
    print('a_task(): before sleep')
    # waiting for something to happen
    await asyncio.sleep(30)
    print('a_task(): after sleep')
    return 42

async def main():
    # Create a Task
    print('main() before create_task')
    task = asyncio.create_task(a_task())
    print('main() task created')

    print('Doing stuff here between task creation and await')
    # Computing 200000! should take few seconds... 
    # use a smaller number if its too slow on your machine
    x = reduce(lambda a,b: a*b, range(1, 200000))
    print('Stuff done')

    print('main() awaiting task')
    task_result = await task
    print('main() task awaited')
    return task_result

#%%
if __name__ == '__main__':
    results = asyncio.run(main())
    print(results)
```

This returns

```
main() before create_task
main() task created
Doing stuff here between task creation and await
Stuff done
main() awaiting task
a_task(): before sleep   <<---- Task only starts running here!!
a_task(): after sleep
main() task awaited
42
```

`a_task` is created before we start computing 200000!, but it's executed only when we call `await task`. Is it possible to make `a_task` start to run *before* we start computing 200000! and keep it running in the background?

I read [the doc](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#asyncio.create_task), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57968602/4690023), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65921782/4690023), etc... they all mention that `task`s are what should be used to execute code in the background, but I can't understand how to run it without hanging the main code.

Comment: `create_task()` is a function that converts the coroutine to a Task object and it does not schedule the coroutine to be executed, To execute this Task we can use `await` keyword or `asyncio.run()` The main use of create_task() is to create concurrent coroutines we can call await on two coroutines and it executes them concurrently.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that the problem here is the following: creating a task with `create_task` does not schedule it for the immediate execution: it needs an `await` or something similar to trigger the switching of the event loop to start running something different. In your current code the creation of task is followed with synchronous code in which case the event loop cannot suspend the execution of `main` and start running the task. One way you can ensure that it would behave the way you expect would be putting `asyncio.sleep(0)` before running the evaluation of the factorial. That way while `main()` is being executed when it'll encounter `await` the event loop will suspend the execution of `main` and switch to `a_task`.

Other approach that can be interesting for you is using `asyncio.gather` [docs link](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#running-tasks-concurrently) to schedule multiple async task and then to suspend the execution of `main` and wait for all of the tasks to complete.

```py
from functools import reduce
import asyncio


async def a_task():
    print("a_task(): before sleep")
    # waiting for something to happen
    await asyncio.sleep(30)
    print("a_task(): after sleep")
    return 42


async def doing_something_else():
    print("We start doing something else")
    x = reduce(lambda a, b: a * b, range(1, 200000))
    print("We finish doing something else")


async def main():
    # Create a Task
    print("main() before create_task")
    task = asyncio.create_task(a_task())
    print("main() task created")
    print("main() before create_task 2")
    task_2 = asyncio.create_task(doing_something_else())
    print("main() task 2 created")

    print("main() gathering tasks")
    # task_result = await task
    await asyncio.gather(task, task_2)
    print("main() tasks finished")
    # return task_result


#%%
if __name__ == "__main__":
    results = asyncio.run(main())
    print(results)
```

Comment: `gather` was a kinda obvious solution, but I wanted to understand the bahaviour of `task` at a bit lower lever. Your solution with `await asyncio.sleep(0)` sounds like the solution I was looking for, even if it sounds a bit "hacky". It would be good it you could expand a little bit on that if you want. But in any case many thanks for the explaination

Comment: Instead of gather you can use await also like this `await task` and `await task_2` it will still execute it concurrently

Comment: It might sound hacky indeed, but here's the deal: while you run only sync code after creating the task it will never start execution, the event loop needs a "trigger" in order to switch the context, and this trigger is awaiting something. There is this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/52209668/5975065 that goes into some cons of using sleep that also links to python github issue, this can be be an interesting read for you.